# SQL SERVER 2017 primary key violation when re-inserting a previously deleted row

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

I deleted 100 (of 500) rows from a table that has a clustered primary key made up of 2 column values. The `WHERE` clause used a column not in any key or index.

```
DELETE myTABLE WHERE data1='0'
```

The rows were deleted, and I ran a query to check myself.

However, I attempted to insert the rows back into myTABLE using...

```
INSERT INTO myTABLE (pkval1, pkval2, data1, data2)
SELECT srcVal1, srcVal2, srcData1, srcData2
FROM mySourceTable
```

In `mySourceTable`, the `srcVal` and `srcVal2` columns form a unique index, but are not the primary key.

The result was an error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_MYTABLE'  Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.myTable'.  The duplicate key value is {a value in srcVal2}

I reviewed all the key values in `mySourceTable`, and they were valid.

Question:  If I deleted the rows, why wouldn't I be able to re-insert them?

I've never had this problem in many years of SQL programming. But I'm tired and I'm sure I'm blind to something simple.

Comment: do you have identity specification setup for this column?

Comment: It's the second part of a unique index.  srcVal1 + srcVal2

Comment: Not possible. A primary key violation error message will include the complete tuple that is a duplicate. [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=91ec3e668c325f3193cecbae7a4575fd).

Comment: I mistyped... srcVal1 and srcVal2 are a unique index, not the primary key.

Comment: Is it possible that there's a duplicated `srcVal1, srcVal2` tuple in the `SELECT` portion of your `INSERT` statement? That'll throw a key violation error when the second tuple tries to write.

Comment: Thanks.  No.  The two comprise a unique index in mySourceTable.

Comment: Sorry but that isn't a "mistype". Just a basic mistake (and perhaps assumption). And the resulting error message will still include the complete tuple. If the error message only includes a single value, then you have made an error somewhere in your DDL or you are using the wrong table. [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f124f45b9a8c59e8f93fa136efc96434)

Comment: If you deleted 100 rows from a 500 row table, there are still 400 rows remaining. One of those remaining 400 rows has a value that conflicts with the new value you're trying to insert.

Comment: One more try. There's no `WHERE` clause in the `INSERT` statement, so what steps are you taking to be sure you're not re-inserting rows that exist? But I'm going to note that all anybody here is doing is guessing because there isn't [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here for us to do more than that.

Comment: Thanks for your help, friends.  I'm going to take another look at what I have and verify that I'm telling you the whole truth.  SMor, I know you're right about the tuple.  I'll investigate and get back to you.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again, all. The problem is resolved.  The problem was in mySourceTable.  While srcVal1+srcVal2 produced unique index values, there was a unique index on pkval2 in myTABLE.  I couldn't see the forest for the trees.  My apologies for all the shortcomings in my post and communication.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in mySourceTable. While srcVal1+srcVal2 produced unique index values, there was a unique index on pkval2 in myTABLE. I couldn't see the forest for the trees.